# Visual Studio 2010 shortcut to find classes and methods?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there any shortcut in Visual studio 2010 to find classes/interfaces?

I was using Resharper few years back to do that. Here now, I don't have the Resharper and looking something similar in Visual studio 2010 which can help me do that.

Right now, I have to use find all "s classname" that's closest I can get.

Comment: full list of shortcuts http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/

Answer (score 325, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 has the "Navigate To" command, which might be what you are looking for. The default keyboard shortcut is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>. [Here is an overview](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/searching-and-navigating-code-in-visual-studio-2010/) of some of the options for navigating in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Beautiful, primary feature I wanted in Resharper without everything else :-)

Comment: Thanks Dear,
I want to know is there any special character i can filter the files with extension,
suppose i have filename 'ABCD.cshtml' is there any way i can filter file like 'ABCD%.cshtml' or something

Comment: Does anyone experience that the 'navigate to' box closes spontaneously while they are typing? It drives me mad. Seems only to happen on the first use after opening Visual Studio.

Comment: @ColonelPanic absolutely, same problem here, and I continue typing in some random spot!!! Have you tried this in VS 2017? Seems to be stable and now rich with options - tbh looks much better than even in resharper.

Comment: `Edit > Navigate To...` in the main menu

Comment: Can we drop the visual-studio tag, leaving just visual-studio-2010 to be clear this is a legacy question, not relevant to the current version?

Comment: @ahcox makes sense - I removed the tag.

Answer (score 74):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: I think that is the Resharper key mapping

Comment: @LeeCampbell It's not. It corresponds to Edit.GoToAll (Global).

Comment: so the default mapping is Ctrl + 1 + F1

Comment: For me it always adds a `#` as a prefix and I always have to delete it first to make it find the defnition...

Answer (score 14):

Try <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> in Visual Studio 2010.

It opens up the *Find Symbol* dialogue which allows you to search for methods, classes, etc.

Comment: do you know what it is for later versions, such as 2013?

Comment: Don't use Visual Studio these days but try http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2013/

Answer (score 6):

Use the "Go To Find Combo Box" with the ">of" command. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> are the standard hotkeys.

For example, go to the combo box (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>) and type: `>of MyClassName`. As you type, intellisense will refine the options in the dropdown.

In my experience, this is faster than *Navigate To* and doesn't bring up another dialog to deal with. Also, this combo box has a lot of other nifty little shortcut commands:

*[Using the Go To Find Combo Box](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/06/16/using-the-go-to-find-combo-box-vstipfind0009.aspx)*

This textbox used to be the default on the Standard toolbar in Visual Studio. It was removed in Visual Studio 2012, so you have to add it back using menu *Tools* → *Customize*. The hotkeys may have changed too: I'm not sure since mine are all customized.

Answer (score 6):

In VS 2022, and I assume also in older versions, you may have to check the shortcuts for finding classes/types. In my case I had to manually configure the shortcut in Tools->Options->Keyboard:
[image]

This is very similar to the ReSharper "Ctrl + T" command, which I have used more often.

Comment: Isn't there a way to add it to the context menu?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> opens the Object Browser in Visual Studio 2010. Find what you're looking for by searching and browsing and filtering the results. See also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. `^K ^R` is better because it puts your caret right in the search box, ready to type your new search, even when the Object Browser is already open.

Set the Browse list on the top left to where you want to look to get started. From there you can use the search box (2nd text box from the top, goes all the way across the Object Browser window) or you can just go through everything from the tree on the left. Searches are temporary but the "selected components" set by the Browse list persists. Set a custom set with the little "..." button just to the right of the list.

Objects, packages, namespaces, types, etc. on the left; fields, methods, constants, etc. on the top right, docstrings on the lower right.

The display mode of a pane can be changed by right-clicking in the empty space of the window; tree organized by assembly/container or by namespace and other preferences.

Items can be right-clicked to find, copy and filter.

For keyboard navigation, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> from anywhere to start a new search, <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute the search you just typed or pasted and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> to make the Object Browser close. <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd><--</kbd> to go back and <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>--></kbd> to go forward through the search history. More can be set; search for "ObjectBrowser" in the keyboard shortcut config.

If the key shortcuts above don't work, Object Browser should be in the View menu somewhere with a different shortcut. If all else fails, search for "ObjectBrowser" under Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard->"Show commands containing".

Answer (score 1):

"Control + ," you will get a search textbox enter your text it will automictic show all.

Answer (score 0):

Left click on a method and press the F12 key to Go To Definition.
[Other Actions also available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsi1p.png)

Comment: He means when files are closed.

Comment: @Alexander - And I knew that based on the question the OP asked, how?

Answer (score -1):

try: ctrl + P

type: @

followed by the name of the class,method or variable name you search for.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272776/visual-studio-2010-shortcut-to-find-classes-and-methods/66084581#comment61944787_36136371

Answer (score -7):

In [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code), the default shortcut for this is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>.

Comment: Why down-votes? This question is tagged with both `visual-studio` and `visual-studio-2010`

Comment: I'm not the down-voter, but Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code are not the same product. In Visual Studio, ctrl+P is the "Print" shortcut...

Comment: @ashes999, you have already told that your answer is wrong, why you don't delete it?

Comment: Please, delete!